# Can we use cryptocurrency mining to verify claims of quantum advantage?

Tags: quantum-advantage, nisq, cryptocurrency

Beginning with the earlier works of work of [Brakerski *et al.*](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/92582/) or the more recent results of [Kahanamoku-Meyer *et al.*](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-022-01643-7), interactive proofs of quantum advantage entail a classical verifier (Vicky) providing a quantum prover (Peggy) a circuit to evaluate a trapdoor claw-free function $f$ in superposition, e.g. Peggy prepares $\sum|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$, and evaluates the first and second register in the Hadamard and computational basis, respectively.  See, e.g., Mahadev's [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kql5dSywvy0) that expands these ideas into her breakthrough procedure to classically verify a quantum computation.

These interactive procedures have Peggy to evaluate certain trapdoor claw-free functions.  I'd like to see if we can modify this approach to use another hash function *outsource the verification* to *cryptocurrency miners*.

That is, consider the following modification combining proof-of-work mining with proof-of-quantumness verification.  I'll initially start off with `SHA256` as the hash function, as that is what is used in the bitcoin network (and I'll relax that requirement below):

1. Let a first register have $m$ qubits, and a second register have $m-1$ qubits.  The quantum computer (Peggy) prepares the registers as $\frac{1}{\sqrt {2^m}}\sum|x\rangle|f(x)\rangle$, where $f(x)$ is the last $m-1$ bits of `SHA256` of $x$.
2. Peggy measures the second register $y=f(x)$ in the computational basis and commits and broadcasts $y$.  This measurement of the second register collapses the first register onto the preimages of $f$ that collide at $y$.  If $f$ is two-to-one, then the two preimages $x_1,x_2$ both hash onto $y$.  Importantly, although Peggy does not *find* the colliding pair $(x_1,x_2)$, she *maintains the pair in superposition*.
3. Peggy measures this first register $d$ in the Hadamard basis and broadcasts and commits $d$.  We should have that $d\cdot (x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ from the Hadamard measurement of the first register.  That is, although Peggy does not announce both preimages (because she can't yet), she announces a *single bit* that she learned about these preimages.
4. Bitcoin miners (Vicky) set their rigs to work, cycling through various $x's$ to find the two preimages $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$.  The test that $d\cdot (x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ is also checked by other clients on the network, once both $(x_1,x_2)$ are broadcast by Vicky.
5. Indeed, Peggy can incentivize miners to find her preimages by offering a smart-contract awarding a certain amount of cryptocurrency to the first miners that broadcast the preimages.

If the miners Vicky are always (or often) able to find pairs of preimages that hash onto the announced $y$ and that also satisfy the orthogonality test with respect to $d$, then this shows that Peggy had possession of preimages in superposition - i.e., she was a quantum computer capable of evaluating $f(x)$, the last $m-1$ bits of `SHA256`, in superposition.

The hash function $f(x)$ need not be `SHA256`, and the miners need not be bitcoin miners; rather, any cryptographically secure hash function that is easily implementable on a quantum circuit may be viable.  But, there needs to be enough cryptocurrency miners that would be incentivized properly to run all the hashes to find $x_1$ and $x_2$.

> **Is such a proof-of-work based proof-of-quantumness realistic in the NISQ era?**

Ideally it would be two-to-one or close to it; I think the the number of collisions on a random oracle, instantiated as a `SHA256` hash, obeys Poisson statistics.  But, as long as the hash is two-to-one often enough, I think enough statistics can be generated to reject the null hypothesis that Peggy was randomly guessing her $d$.

Comment: Is that what cryptominers do? Do they find inverses of some hash function given its output?

Comment: @MonteNero yes, that’s my understanding. Miners for cryptocurrencies like bitcoin run speciality ASICS to hunt for a preimage that hashes on to a string ending with a bunch of 0’s. I’m proposing to repurpose these ASICS to find preimages hashing on to a string that was broadcast by a quantum computer.

Comment: Is it already established that getting a tuple $(d,f(x))$ from a quantum computer and verifying classically that $d$ pertains to colliding $x_1$ and $x_2$ is a proof of quantumness?

Comment: @MonteNero modulo some properties of $f$, this follows I think from the work of Brakerski et al., mentioned above. That is, $f$ should have an “adaptive hardcore bit” property which essentially means that you can’t learn anything about $x_2$ when you know $x_1$.  This is satisfied I think with LWE. Kahanoko-Meyer et al.’s paper is based on $x^2\bmod N$, which doesn’t satisfy this property, but they use some other neat tricks to mitigate it. I don’t know or claim to know whether or how often it’s genetically satisfied by something like SHA256, but I would guess yes..

Comment: Well I guess technically it’s a proof-of-nonclassicalness, much as Bell violations are proofs that the world is not classical.

Comment: Bell violations are absolutely no proof of anything concerning locality/nonclassicalness; in as much the AM–GM inequality used for negative numbers gives the length of a triangle in a parallel universe.

Comment: @quantum my comment above was to show that proofs of quantum advantage/supremacy are analogous to Bell tests. Sure the hypotheses can be questioned, in both cases. But that wasn’t where I was going.

Comment: @MarkS I'm not sure I did get it correctly, but my first guess would be that this is not realistic because while classical players solve the problem in $O\left(2^m\right)$, quantum ones do it in $O\left(\sqrt{2^m}\right)$, don't they? Having a quantum access to $f$ means that you still have to perform amplitude amplification so that you measure $y$ with high probability. In the NISQ area $m$ has to be chosen not too large because a quadratic speedup is not that great, but not too small because NISQ computers are kind of slow when compared to classical ones. Is something off in my reasoning?

Comment: @TristanNemoz I’ll write more when I have access to a proper keyboard, but a quantum computer doesn’t *find both* preimages (which would require amplitude amplification), but only finds a single string $d$ that is orthogonal to the XOR of the preimages. This only requires doing a Hadamard gate on the first register. This much has been known since Brakerski et al. A classical computer needs to find both preimages to get a string orthogonal to the XOR of the preimages. A quantum computer just needs one call to the hash function $f$ (and run the Hadamard on the first register).

Comment: My understanding is that we can't know both $x_1$ and $x_2$. Getting only one $x_i$ doesn't make sense. However, measuring the superposition of $x_i$s in the Hadamard basis allows to encode information into $d$ so that classical verifiers could make sure that a QC had the necessary superposition. I find this idea pretty cool. But I'm still struggling to understand why this is a proof of quantumness. In the end, to verify the result, we run a lengthy classical computation which essentially accomplishes the same task (it finds the colliding inputs). So whatever a QC did, miners can also do.

Comment: @MonteNero yeah, you got it. Everything you said is correct. My approach is a “proof-of-quantumness” only insofar as the *miners* have to cycle through a whole bunch of preimages, while a quantum computer only needs one call to the hash function. Quantum computing resources grow linearly  with the number of qubits in the preimage, while classical computers resources grow exponentially. The other interactive protocols rely on trapdoor hash functions, which has other advantages (but may not be NISQ-implantable.)

Comment: @MarkS Thanks for the explanation. Yes, that's a good point. Here we have a somewhat unfair situation, though. A QC produces $d$ and $f(x)$. We can't do much with it. But miners actually find both $x_1$ and $x_2$. So their work is actually useful and solves the inverse problem. I'm not sure if what I wrote makes sense in the context of "proof of quantumness".

Comment: @MarkS I'm still struggling to understand how could a QC perform this, could you write the procedure in your post or point me to a theorem/procedure in a paper that describes this please? Thanks in advance, I find the question quite interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very cool idea! So the main benefit you're hoping for is kind of a publicly-verifiable proof-of-quantumness, rather than than Mahadev's, which seems to depend on knowing the trapdoor of some function (so only one person could be convinced at a time).

To fake a proof, the prover would need to either (a) find $d$ such that there exists $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $f(x_1)|_m=f(x_2)|_m$ (i.e., restricted to the last $m$ bits) and $d\cdot (x_1\oplus x_2)=0$ or (b) produce one of $x_1$ or $x_2$. I can't think of a way to reduce this to a known hardness property of a hash function $f$, but this is at most as hard as $m$-bit collision-resistance: if I have a hash collision oracle for the last $m$ bits, then I can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ that collide on $m$ bits and output any vector orthogonal to these in the first case, or one of them in the second.

A key fact here is that finding $m$-bit collisions has complexity $\approx 2^{m/2}$, not $2^m$.

The problem for the miners is, given $d$ and an $m$-bit string $s$, find $x_1$ and $x_2$ that collide and that $f(x_1)\vert_m=f(x_2)\vert_m=s$ and $d\cdot(x_1\oplus x_2)$. This doesn't quite reduce to regular pre-image search, since if there is only one pre-image, it might not return anything. But it seems like it's about as hard as two generic $m$-bit preimage searches.

So, I don't think this works because of the square root gap: the prover just needs *any* collision, while the verifier needs to find a collision matching the output given by the prover. When I looked it up just now, bitcoin has 28 bit difficulty, so you should be able to find collisions in about $2^{14}$ hash iterations -- I think a single properly programmed GPU could solve that in under a second. More generally, this means a cheating verifier with hardware proportional to (total bitcoin network hardware)/(square root of current challenge level). I think this will end up increasing absolutely with the size of the bitcoin network, but as a *proportion* of the network it will decrease.

I also have zero faith in this being a NISQ technology. Computing hash functions in superposition is a high-depth circuit; [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.10982.pdf) estimates a gate depth that I think means 152,000 sequential gates for one SHA-256 call and about 2600 logical qubits. That's just to compute the hash function once, so that's what the quantum computer needs to do. Since the pre-image space is restricted, we could pre-compute parts of the circuit for fixed parts of the input, but a good hash function diffuses its input quickly and so we don't get much benefit.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-answer, made CW (also, this is more of an extended comment to @SamJacques' excellent and accepted answer above).**

As Sam indicates the naïve approach outlined in the question is likely insecure, as it is amenable to a [birthday-attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack) from the prover Peggy.

Given a two-to-one hash function $f$ from $m+1$ qubits onto $m$ qubits, a cheating prover can find her own collisions $y=f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ in time $\sqrt{2^m}$, and announce a random $d$ orthogonal to $x_1$ and $x_2$.  Vicky the verifier's job is harder, as Vicky must find both $x_1$ and $x_2$ only given $y$, and this can only be done in time $2^m$.  Thus, if $f$ were two-to-one, the amount of security needed means that Vicky wouldn't ever keep up to be able to validate Peggy's output.

However, a random oracle from $m+1$ qubits to $m$ qubits is not, generically, two-to-one (although the expected number of collisions is two).  Indeed I think the number of collisions should obey the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), much as defects randomly sprinkled on chips on a wafer do.

I used to think this lack of a two-to-one response from random hash functions was a *bug* in the proposal, but it might be a *feature*.  **We might be able to leverage this to repair the proposal in light of Sam's birthday attack.**

For example, if miners are incentivized properly, then they should find all of the preimages that hash onto the broadcast image.  Accordingly if they only find one preimage, then we can assume that there was only one preimage to be found (if the mining reward were high enough).

We can use this to look at all of Peggy's announcements, and plot a histogram of the number of preimages found by the miners.  For an honest Peggy, this histogram should obey the Poisson statistics, with $\lambda=2$ as there are twice as many input strings $2^{m+1}$ as there are output strings $2^m$ and the average number of collisions is two.

Each time there is only one preimage (or, three or more preimages), Peggy's announced $d$ can be random.  Each time there are two preimages, the announced $d$ better satisfy the orthogonality test with respect to the XOR of the preimages found by the miners.

But, an honest or even a cheating Peggy has no way of knowing, *a-priori*, how many preimages each of her announced $y$ has.  Sure, she could use the birthday attack to broadcast $y$ if she's able to find collisions $x_1$ and $x_2$, but she also has to announce just as many $y$ that only have a single preimage, so as to satisfy the Poisson test.

Let a cheating Peggy announce a $d$ and a $y$ that she hopes only has one preimage.  But, she should not be able to know whether her announced $y$ has one, or two, or more than two preimages.  If her $y$ happens to have two preimages, she will get caught in her lie if $d$ isn't orthogonal to $x_1\oplus x_2$.  Some appeal to the Chernoff bound and/or Hoeffding's inequality could find this cheat.

---

The bigger issue that I've been sweeping under the rug is of course that `SHA256` is most likely *not* implementable in the NISQ-era.  Sam is right in that we don't need to do a full Grover run of `SHA256`, but even one single evaluation is too deep of a circuit for now.  I think estimates of the number of qubits can be brought down, but the circuit depth may always be too high, and the overall fidelity too low, for this to be realistic.

Comment: Interesting change. To fake a proof, I would try to fake the Poisson statistics, but this requires knowing how many pre-images a given element has. I suppose this the prover's problem is now a decisional pre-image problem (decide whether $x$ has $k$ preimages), while the verifier's problem is search (find all preimages). I don't know these have a reduction or separation for random functions. Might be worth asking on crypto.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, I was just thinking of how to frame the question on crypto.stack!

Comment: Thinking about this more, and security will be a little harder. For example, with 3 pre-images, you get a funny distribution after the Hadamard transform: strings orthogonal to 1 or 2 of the preimages are more likely than those orthogonal to 0 or 3 of them. And for 4 preimages, it gets trickier still. I think soundness will decrease with the number of pre-images, possibly quite badly

Comment: @SamJaques This issue may be countered because a Poisson distribution doesn't have to have much of a right tail, and you can choose a $\lambda$ with the number of output $y$ with 3 or more preimages small. Indeed, you could consider a hash from $m-2$ qubits to $m$ qubits ($\lambda=1/4$). In such a case, for an honest quantum computer running with perfect fidelity, roughly 78% of the announced $y$ have only one preimage; roughly 19% of the announced $y$ have exactly two preimages, and less than 3% of the announced $y$ have more than two preimages.  You can throw away these edge cases, right?

Comment: Suppose I don't have a quantum computer and I just pick a random $x$, output the last $m$ bits of $f(x)$, and then give a random $d$. If there's only one pre-image, I pass the test always! If there's two pre-images, I pass the test with probability $1/4$: I can output one of the two pre-images if that's what's required, and my $d$ has probability $1/2$ of being orthogonal to the two pre-images. Suppose I somehow find a way to always cheat with 3 or more preimages. Then the probably of catching me cheating is only about 9.5%. I think this means we need about 890 repetitions for 128 bit soundnes

Comment: @SamJaques I think that's right or close to my math, and your attack is what I would do, but, 
 $1-(0.905)^n$ is exponential with $n$, right?  A 9.5% chance to catch a cheat is still pretty high, if this can be amplified be amplified to be essentially 100% with repetition. Or, were you suggesting that 890 repetitions is reasonable?

Comment: Yeah it can be amplified to $1-2^{-128}$ with 890 repetitions. So it could work! But I'm not sure there aren't other attacks.